# Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable a.e. Is $x \rightarrow Df(x)$ a Borel measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm stuck proving this.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable a.e. Is $x \rightarrow Df(x)$ a Borel measurable function? $Df(x) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ represents the evaluation of the differential of $f$ at the point $x$. We can suppose (from previous reasoning on the problem) that differentials are bounded i.e. there exists $K$ such that $||Df(x)|| \leq K$ for every $x$. I don't know if it is as simple as writing the terms of the matrix $Df(x)$ as limit of measurable functions (as they are partial derivatives of $f$) or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as you think.

Let $[\delta_n(x)]_i = \frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n}e_i)-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$, then each component of $\delta_n$ is measurable, hence the limit function $x \mapsto \lim_n \delta_n(x) = Df(x)$ is measurable.